# FFMPEG add additional audio track in video (mix 2 audio)

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to add an audio file on a video without removing the original video's audio.

I want basically a video file that retains his original audio and to add it another audio

(the audio I want to add is longer than the duration of the video so I would rather that the new video ends at his original duration)

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to mix the new audio or add it as a separate stream?

Comment: I want the new audio be added at the video so that I have a new video file with retains the original audio and the new audio (the 2 audio are mixed)

Answer (score 5):

Basic command syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i newaudio
  -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amix=duration=shortest[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]"
  -c:v copy out.mp4
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ffmpeg -i V.MP4 -i A1.WAV -i A2.WAV -filter_complex "[1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy Output.MP4
```

Comment: (1) You seem to have slightly misunderstood the question.  The user has a video file which includes an audio track, and a separate audio file — not a video and *two* separate audio files.  (2) Your answer appears to be very similar to [Gyan’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1274748/150988#1274758).  Can you explain the differences and justify that yours is better? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.